# Различия в размере структуры ( c++)

Tags: c++, char, struct, sizeof

Вставляю код

```
struct Person
{ 
    int n; char name[10]; 
} p;
```

Потом узнаю размер структуры. 
sizeof(p);
после чего результат - 16.
Почему так? Сколько char же занимает 1 байт, 10 сhar занимают 10 байт. int же занимает 4 байта, а структура 1 байт? Откуда ещё 1 байт?

Comment: "...а структура 1 байт" - а это вы о чем?

Comment: Спрашивал, верное ли моё предположение.

Comment: Так в чем заключается предположение? Что означает "...а структура 1 байт"?

Comment: @AnT, автор предполагает, что структура без мемберов имеет размер 1 байт.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ответ прост - *выравнивание*. Компилятор выравнивает в памяти поля структуры так, чтобы обеспечить максимальное быстродействие (или обеспечить выполнение затребованного ключами компилятора выравнивания :))

Вот такой код (VC++ 2015)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

#pragma pack(8)
struct Person1
{ 
    int n; char name[10]; 
} p1;

#pragma pack(1)
struct Person2
{ 
    int n; char name[10]; 
} p2;


int main()
{
    cout << sizeof(p1) << endl;
    cout << sizeof(p2) << endl;
}
```

А вот его вывод:

```
16
14
```

Хотя структуры функционально одинаковы, выравнивание применено разное...

Comment: Да как так-то? Ща покомпилю

Comment: @AshenOne курите data alignment, почему он устроен так, как устроен, и т.п. Ну и еще про то, что такое структура и класс, раз Вы думаете, что она имеет размер 1 байт.